# has_many through, vs belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a bit confused on what is the best way to implement the following functionality in a recruitment app :

All Users must fill out 1 "common_application_form".

In the common application form, there will be options like graduation year, a multiselect picklist of preferred industries, a resume attachment etc.

All users will be able to be filtered by their answers to the questions. I.e anyone who graduated in 2005, and prefers to work in sales.

I'm thinking there can be 2 ways of doing this --

**Option 1: Users has_one common_app**

In the common app, create grad_year:integer, pref_industries:string, etc.

And then filter by something like this -- >

```
User.includes(:common_app).where('common_app.grad_year = 2005')
```

The downside to this is that I am not sure how I would make the multiselect picklist for industries work. Would the datatype be string? How would the filtering work?

**Option 2 has_many through common_app**

Option 2 can be some sort of has_many through association, via a common_app model. I'm thinking this might be the best way to go, but I'm a bit confused with the has_many association, and am having trouble structuring the database.

In your opinion, would you go for option 1, if yes, how would you deal with the multiselect picklist?

If option 2, what would you do?

And of course, maybe I'm completely in the wrong path, in which case let me know :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 makes sense to me.

With respect to the preferred industries, I'd see it as a join between the user and a list of industries -- a UserIndustry model.

If you wanted to apply attributes to it (such as a strength of preference or priority) then User and Industry would both has_many UserIndustry, which would belong_to both of them, and Industry and User both mutually has_many through UserIndustry.

Comment: Very cool. In this case, I would have most of the options that are not multiselect picklists part of the common_app model, but separate out the ones that are multiselect as a many_to_many relationship. Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1):

David's answer is correct, you can have a look to this screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised?view=asciicast

I made an app like this a couple of times but having many multiselect and select answers. I took the approach of making one model called option with `name:string` `group:integer`, etc...

In the option model I had:

```
def self.by_group(group_number)
  where(:group => group_number)
end
```

And I could extract the option collections to build the form with `options.by_group(1)` in example.